# MVC Accessing navigation property for listboxFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

At first I should say i am compeletely newbie in MVC.
 I have 3 Objects

```
 public partial class Magazine
{
    public Magazine()
    {
        this.NumberTitles = new HashSet<NumberTitle>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MagYear { get; set; }
    public int MagNo { get; set; }
    public int MagSeason { get; set; }
    public string MagYear2 { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<NumberTitle> NumberTitles { get; set; }
}

public partial class NumberTitle
{
    public NumberTitle()
    {
        this.Articles = new HashSet<Article>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MagazineId { get; set; }
    public int TitleId { get; set; }
    public int position { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    public virtual Magazine Magazine { get; set; }
    public virtual Title Title { get; set; }
}


public partial class Title
{
    public Title()
    {
        this.ChildrenTitle = new HashSet<Title>();
        this.NumberTitles = new HashSet<NumberTitle>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TitleText { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ParentId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Title> ChildrenTitle { get; set; }
    public virtual Title ParentTitle { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<NumberTitle> NumberTitles { get; set; }
}
```

In a View I want to have TextBox to show Magazine Number and 2 List boxes. one shows all the Available Titles and the Other just selected Titles for that Magazine Number.So I have made View Model

```
public class NumberTitleViewModel
{       
    public Magazine Magazine { get; set; }
    public List<NumberTitle> NumberTitles { get; set; }
}
```

this is in controller. how can i get the list of titles for specified MagazineId

```
    public ActionResult EditTitle(int id)
    {
        Func<IQueryable<Magazine>, IOrderedQueryable<Magazine>> orderByFunc = null;
        Expression<Func<Magazine, bool>> filterExpr = null;
        if (id>0)
        {
            filterExpr = p => p.Id.Equals(id);
        }

        Magazine magazine = unitOfWork.MagazineRepository.Get(filter: filterExpr, orderBy: orderByFunc, includeProperties: "").SingleOrDefault();
        NumberTitleViewModel numberTitleViewMode = new NumberTitleViewModel();
        numberTitleViewMode.Magazine = magazine;
        Expression<Func<NumberTitle, bool>> filterExpr2 = null;
        if (id > 0)
        {
            filterExpr2 = p => p.MagazineId.Equals(id);
        }
        var numberTitles = unitOfWork.NumberTitleRepository.Get(filterExpr2, null, includeProperties: "Title").ToList();

        var titles = unitOfWork.TitleRepository.Get(null, null, "");
        numberTitleViewMode.NumberTitles = numberTitles; ///this part doesn't show the Titles. how should access the TitleName not Id
        ViewBag.titles = new SelectList(titles, "Id", "TitleText");
        return View("../Panel/Magazine/EditTitle", "_BasicLayout", numberTitleViewMode);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you have in your view but you should have something like:

```
@using NameSpace.Models
@model NameSpace.Models.NumberTitleViewModel
```

Then you can do something like this in your view:

```
 foreach (NumberTitles item in   @Model)
    {
        <label>@item.Title.TitleText</label>
    }
```

Not exact but should get you close to what you need

Comment: how should i pass two model from controller to view?

Comment: It looks like you already are in your return View(string,string,object)